# MS Word VBA: Saving File, runtime error 5152

Tags: vba, ms-word

I posted a question recently about getting my mail merge document to split and save. After finding some code online, I was able to combine it with my own code to get the document to split and create a name that I wanted. However, now when the code goes to save the document, it puts out a 5152 error, and I have no clue on how to go about it. This is what my code looks like and the error occurs at the ActiveDocument.SaveAs filename:=Fullname, fileformat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, AddToRecentFiles:=False

```
Option Explicit

Sub Splitter()

' splitter Macro

' Macro created by Doug Robbins to save each letter created by a mailmergeas a separate file.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Program As String
Dim DocName As String
Dim Letters As Integer, Counter As Integer
Dim filename, extension, Fullname, Mask As String

Letters = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Counter = 1
While Counter < Letters
'program = ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Program_Outcomes_PlanReport_Name").Value
DocName = "Reports" & LTrim$(Str$(Counter))  'Generic name of document
ActiveDocument.Sections.First.Range.Cut
Documents.Add
Selection.Paste
ActiveDocument.Sections(2).PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionContinuous

filename = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
            filename = Replace(filename, Chr$(13), "")
            filename = Replace(filename, Chr$(10), "")
            filename = Replace(filename, "/", "_")
            filename = Replace(filename, "&", "_")
            extension = ".docx"
            DocName = "E:\assessment rubrics" & filename & " - Academic Program Review - " & Format(Now(), Mask)
            Fullname = DocName & extension

ActiveDocument.SaveAs filename:=Fullname, fileformat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, AddToRecentFiles:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
Counter = Counter + 1
Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Im assuming it has to be something with how the path to the file is written because The error message reads:

`Run-Time error '5152':
This is not a valid file name.
Try one or more of the following:
*Check the path to make sure it was typed coerrectly.
*Select a file from the list of files and folders.`

Comment: First of all, is `assessment rubrics` a folder name or first words of your file name? If it is a folder name, then you should change it to `"E:\assessment rubrics\"`. Also change fileformat to `fileformat:=wdFormatXMLDocument` since it has a `docx` extension.

Comment: @Tehscript I did what you said, but it is still giving the 5152 error

Comment: Can you debug.print Fullname and share with us? It might still have restricted characters in it even if you think you replaced all of them.

Comment: When I do that it puts out:            
E:\assessment_rubrics\Templates\Program: Art-Studio Art BFA - Academic Program Review - 8/23/2017 3:04:28 PM.docx

Comment: Could the : after the word "Program be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

cvtstr(These characters /|?*<>:"\ are not allowed in your filename. Use the function below:

```
Function cvtstr(strIn As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Const str = "\/|?*<>"":"
    cvtstr = strIn
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        cvtstr = Replace(cvtstr, Mid$(str, i, 1), " ")
    Next i
End Function
```

and then your code should be:

```
    Dim filename As String, Fullname As String, Mask As String, filepath As String
    .
    .
    .
    filename = cvtstr(Replace(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text, "Templates\", "")) 'this part is temporary solution. You actually need to distinguish filepath and filename in ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text    
    filename = Left(filename, Len(filename) - 1) & " - Academic Program Review - " & cvtstr(Format(Now(), Mask)))

    filepath = "E:\assessment_rubrics\Templates\"

    FullName = filepath & filename & ".docx"
```

EDIT:

It is not a good practice to combine filepath and filename, but since you extract it from the paragraph, until you find a better solution to improve your code, you can do the following:

Use the function below:

```
Function cvtstr(strIn As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Const str = "/|?*<>"":"
    cvtstr = strIn
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        cvtstr = Replace(cvtstr, Mid$(str, i, 1), " ")
    Next i
End Function
```

and use the following lines in your code

```
Filename = cvtstr(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text)
Filename = Left(Filename, Len(Filename) - 1)
extension = ".docx"
DocName = "E:\assessment rubrics\" & Filename & " - Academic Program Review - " & cvtstr(Format(Now(), Mask)))
FullName = DocName & extension
```

Comment: I've never used a function before, so would I add the function into my code or would I create a new module, add it there, and then call it using the second part you posted?

Comment: Thank you! Ill get to work on getting it put in there and hopefully everything runs smooth!

Comment: I believe the 5152 error is resolved but now it says i cannot save because of a file permission error.

Comment: @Cocoberry2526 It should be also related to an illegal character. Can you debug.print Fullname again?

Comment: This is what it puts out: E  assessment rubrics Program  Art-Teaching Certif BA BS
 - Academic Program Review - 8 23 2017 3 28 38 PM.docx

Comment: It doesn't show it in the comment but there is also some kind of little black bullet point after the BA BS part. I didn't know if that meant anything

Comment: @Cocoberry2526 yeah sure I did not pay attention to that. Please try the updated code. If you still have the same permission error I can think of a solution.

Comment: I replaced the code and now its giving the 5152 error again. The debug.print Fullname is putting out E:\assessment rubrics\Program  Art-Studio Art BA BS  - Academic Program Review - 8 23 2017 3 39 48 PM.docx    with a bullet point after the BA BS

Comment: I tried the new code and the file permission error is back, the debug.print Fullname shows E:\assessment_rubrics\Program  Creative Writing BFA
 - Academic Program Review - 8 23 2017 3 45 47 PM.docx  with no bullet point.

Comment: @Cocoberry2526 I see where the problem is. You are declaring your filename with folder names. You should avoid this.If the folder name is dynamic then declare it separately and filename separately as well. I will update my code, and you can change it according to your needs.

Comment: @Cocoberry2526 I updated the code. Well I did it supposing the `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text` is `Templates\Program: Art-Studio Art BFA`. I can see you have other dynamic folders like `Program`. The best practice is separating folderpath and filename. But if you cannot do that, a workaround might be to change the Const str in the function like this `Const str = "/|?*<>"":"`

Comment: it is still giving the permission error, was I supposed to change anything in the code? It all looked right to me for how I had things named.

Comment: I just saw your other comment, Program actually isn't a folder name but its apart of the text where the next part comes from.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152680/discussion-between-tehscript-and-cocoberry2526).

Answer (score 0):

This is what my code looks like right now

```
Function cvtstr(strIn As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Const str = "/|?*<>"":"
    cvtstr = strIn
    For i = 1 To Len(str)
        cvtstr = Replace(cvtstr, Mid$(str, i, 1), " ")
    Next i
End Function


Sub Splitter()

' splitter Macro

' Macro created by Doug Robbins to save each letter created by a mailmergeas a separate file.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Program As String
Dim DocName As String
Dim Letters As Integer, Counter As Integer
Dim filename, extension, Fullname, filepath, Mask As String

Letters = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Counter = 1
While Counter < Letters
'program =  ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Program_Outcomes_PlanReport_Name").Value
DocName = "Reports" & LTrim$(str$(Counter))  'Generic name of document
ActiveDocument.Sections.First.Range.Cut
Documents.Add
Selection.Paste
'ActiveDocument.Sections(2).PageSetup.SectionStart = wdSectionContinuous

Filename = cvtstr(ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text)
Filename = Left(Filename, Len(Filename) - 1)
extension = ".docx"
DocName = "E:\assessment rubrics\" & Filename & " - Academic Program Review - " & cvtstr(Format(Now(), Mask)))
FullName = DocName & extension

ActiveDocument.SaveAs filename:=Fullname, fileformat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False

ActiveWindow.Close
Counter = Counter + 1
Wend

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```